# ssh multiple hosts with respective users

Tags: shell-script, for

I am trying to loop through multiple remote servers with respective users and ssh and run some command.
I tried, something like in shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Q_HOST=host1 host2 host3  #list of hosts
Q_USER=user1 user2 user3  #list of users
for host in Q_HOST; user in Q_USER;
do
ssh $user@host df -h
done
```

but I think this is not proper way to loop like this, can you guys please guide me on how to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the syntax for assigning to arrays slightly wrong, and your loop can't work like that in `bash`.  In fact, the loop that you've written looks *almost* like what's possible to do in the `zsh` shell.  You also have forgotten to double quote your variables.

---

For a `zsh` solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/zsh

hosts=( host1 host2 host3 host4 )    # array of hosts
users=( user1 user2 user3 user4 )    # array of users

# loop over these and do the ssh thing
for user host in ${users:^hosts}; do
    ssh $user@$host df -h
done
```

The parameter substitution  `${users:^hosts}` is special to the `zsh` shell and would result in a list of elements from the two arrays `users` and `hosts`, alternating between the two. For the example above, this would generate the list `user1 host1 user2 host2 user3 host3 user4 host4`.

A `for` loop in `zsh` can set several separate variables, so we use this to pick out the username-hostname pair in each iteration and call `ssh`.

Note that quoting of variables is not really needed in the `zsh` shell as the shell won't split them on whitespaces or perform filename globbing on them by default.

---

A `bash` solution:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

hosts=( host1 host2 host3 host4 )    # array of hosts
users=( user1 user2 user3 user4 )    # array of users

# set the positional parameters to the hosts
set -- "${hosts[@]}"

# Loop over the users.
# In each iteration, ssh to $1 for $user, then
# shift the next host into $1 when done.
for user in "${users[@]}"; do
        ssh "$user@$1" df -h
        shift
done
```

This avoids having to deal with array indices to pair up the elements of the two arrays. It does this by looping over the elements of one of the arrays while at the same time shifting off successive elements of the other, which are kept in the list of positional parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Kusalananda, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's exactly one user for each host, you can put the lists into *arrays* and loop over the indices of one of the arrays (doesn't really matter which one):

```
#!/bin/bash

Q_HOST=(host1 host2 host3)  #array of hosts
Q_USER=(user1 user2 user3)  #array of users

for i in ${!Q_HOST[@]}; do
  host="${Q_HOST[i]}"
  user="${Q_USER[i]}"

  ssh "$user"@"$host" "df -h"

done
```

You might also want to look at `parallel-ssh` (`pssh`) for tasks like this.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/bin/bash
Q_HOST="host1 host2 host3"
#list of hosts. 
Q_USER="user1 user2 user3"
#list of users 
for host in Q_HOST; do
  for user in Q_USER; do
    echo "${user}@${host}"
   ssh ${user}@${host} df -h
  done
done
```

Comment: Check your syntax (there are missing `$`). Also, this would do all combinations of hosts and users.